# UDP packet captured by wireshark but not by application

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

I have an application that sends files over a one-way-link connection.
basically there's a sender app that sends files over udp
and there's a receiver that knows how to read the packets and transform them into files back.

the application works great in several test envrioments.
e.g: from my computer to another computer in my LAN.

Now, I have a strange scenario where I don't receive any packets from the OS but I do see the packets on Wireshark. the packets look fine:

1. MACs are fine.
2. IP's are correct.
3. Ports are correct.
4. I have set a static arp entry on both the sender PC and the receiver PC
5. Both are windows 7 SP1 I7 2600 and 16GB RAM
6. Sender and receiver have 2 NIC's. one to the lan the one to each other.
7. The sender is connected to the receiver with a one-way-link cable. Meaning packets can only go from the sender to the receiver.
8. When the receiver is down, and the sender sends data: ICMP packets are transmitted from the reciver saying "port unreachable" but if the receiver is up it doesn't happen.
9. Wireshark sniffs packets both on promiscous and not promiscous mode.

I also tried listening to data with python. got nothing.

Are there any windows logs I can look at to see why the packets won't get to my application? Any other ideas for how to diagnose this?

Thanks

Comment: is there maybe a software firewall running that is blocking the packets?  Wireshark could be capturing packets at a layer underneath the firewall, which could explain why Wireshark sees the packets and applications do not.

Comment: No firewall, forgot to mention

Comment: Please learn to format your Q/A using paragraphs. As such, it is a big compact unpleasant block of text that's not inviting and require some effort from the reader.

Comment: (I've edited it for you, and my edit was accepted by reviewer, but please do it yourself next time if you hope to get some readers)

Comment: The first thing that I would do is to replace the one-way-link cable with a regular Ethernet cable, to see if that is the problem.